# Query always return null with passed variable in php

Tags: php, algorithm

I have this (not working) code to delete a file from directory:

```
function deleteImage($deleteId){

    //This query always return null
        $query="SELECT trans.image FROM trans WHERE trans.ID_trans=$deleteId";
    $data=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
    $path="somedir/".$d['image'];
    if(unlink($path)) return true;
}
if($_GET){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $delete=false;
    $delete=deleteImage($id);
    if($delete){
       "bla..bla..blaa"
    }else{
       "bla..bla..blaa"
    }
}
```

But when i do this, which just put it all together, it worked:

```
if($_GET){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $query="SELECT trans.image FROM trans WHERE trans.ID_trans=$id";
    $data=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
    $path="somedir/".$d['image'];
    if(unlink($path)){
       "bla..bla..blaa"
    }else{
       "bla..bla..blaa"
    }
}
```

I have no clue why. Any clue or hint or something i can read i'll be thankful.

Comment: Replace your first code's return line as `if(unlink($path)) return true; else return false;` and see if it's working or not.

Comment: Debug these variables like `$query`, `$deleteId`, `$d` to find the problem. You can use `var_dump()` for an example.

Comment: @biesior I've done it and the ```$deletedId``` return the passed value. And I tried to debug the ```$path``` and it only return ```somedir/```

Comment: @Yasir Mushtaq it's still not working

Comment: @farhan What error you are getting?

Comment: @Yasir Mushtaq nothing. It just straight to the ```else```

Comment: It is very likely that the function does not know `$connect`. Try to add `global $connect;` at the start of the function.

Comment: @Paul T it's not working either. I put it like this:
```function deleteImage($deleteId){
global $connect;
```

Comment: Then check your server error log to see if you are getting any notices or other errors. If all of that code is in the same file, temporarily add this statement at the top of the file after the opening `<?php` tag: `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` then save and reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$connect` variable is undefined for the function, you should use `global $connect` at the start of your function:

```
function deleteImage($deleteId){
    global $connect;
    $query="SELECT trans.image FROM trans WHERE trans.ID_trans=$deleteId";
    $data=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
    $path="somedir/".$d['image'];
    if(unlink($path)) return true;
}
```